# If I am given a function f1() that can give me random number 0 or 1, can I write f2() and f199() with perfectly even distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say, if I am given a function `f1()` that can give me a random number of either 0 or 1, and it is perfectly evenly distributed probability, then

1. Can a function `f2()` that gives be a random number of either 0, 1, 2 be made using `f1()`? (need to be also perfectly evenly distributed)
2. What about `f199()`, for a random number from 0 to 199. (also perfectly evenly distributed).  I think I saw a problem described as `f200()`, for a random number from 1 to 200, but that's is just the `f199()` here plus one.

Can it be proven that it cannot be done? (or have a way to have it done?)

Comment: what you want to do is simulate an $n$-sided dice using a fair coin.

Comment: How long do you have for the function to end?

Comment: There are ways to do it, most of them involve throwing a dice an undefined number of times.

Comment: @dREaM so it is a known problem?

Comment: @Hetebrij isn't it true that... no matter how many times you loop through, it is still finite?

Comment: Consider the answer by Peter, the probability of getting $11$ turn after turn dimishes, but never really becomes $0$, so the chance of needing more than $n$ turns, for any number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is positive.

Comment: This is discussed at length here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29204/how-to-simulate-a-die-given-a-fair-coin

Comment: You can view it that way : If we throw a $6$-sided dice and we only consider the throws with result $1$ and $2$, they will have the same chance to appear.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with a simple trick.

Generate a binary random string with the length you need to generate the numbers $0,...,n$ and simply do not consider the binary string, if the number is at least $n+1$.

Example for $n=2$ :

Generate binary blocks with length $2$ to get an equal-distribution sequence with $0,1,2$.

- If the block $00$ appears, choose digit $0$
- If the block $01$ appears, choose digit $1$
- If the block $10$ appears, choose digit $2$
- If the block $11$ appears, skip it.

  You could also generate formally the numbers $0,1,2,3$ ($3$, if $11$ appears) and delete all the $3's$ afterwards.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example for the case of how `f2()` is expressed using `f1()`

Comment: The idea is as follows. Suppose you want to pick a number between $1$ and $5$ with a normal dice. Then a possible method is to through it until the outcome is different from $6$.

Comment: well, then... the distribution is skewed towards 0 and 1, i think, because when 0 comes out first (as for 00 and 01), you accept those resultant number regardless.  When 1 comes out first, you are extra selective

Comment: no no, he flips all the coins at once, and if the number is larger than desired, he rethrows everthing.  This method gives uniform probability. The only downside is there is a small chance it will take a really long time.

Comment: intuition says... if my maximum is `100000` in binary, then as soon as the first bit is `1` and the rest is anything other than `1`, then you throw it away... so this number is very hard to appear... but I actually simulated the "throw away" method, and it came out evenly distributed.  Actually, if in high school, I might have proposed the "throw away" method, and then the classmate who is 1 year elder than me will point to me that it is not evenly distributed... but I wonder why this time it is counter-intuitive... it feels like another Monty Hall...

Comment: so I suppose you mean using Bayesian formula, I can find that binary `10000000` is as likely to show up as `101` even with the "easy throw away" situation of `10000000` ... hmm... my self-confidence is shattered twice today by this and by Monty Hall

Comment: is this generate n-side dice by a fair coin problem usually part of a college curriculum? I took Probability and Statistic a long time ago and can't remember... but see, I saw people generating a number from 1 to 256 and then do a `mod 200` and think now there is an evenly distributed number and that is obviously wrong (again by my intuition). I saw another person do it by "divide and conquer": toss a coin and choose the left half or right half, and then recursively... but I think it is uneven but now I am not so sure

Comment: Anything more we'd better move it to chatroom, but the divide and conquer is a standard recursion technique: like if 4 numbers: 1 2 3 4, throw a coin, if head, then choose 1,2 and if tail, then choose 3, 4. Now just throw a coin again on the 1, 2 or 3, 4 previous selected. Now you have a perfect evenly distributed probability, but I don't see how it would work if it is 3 items. If you do searching for an item in a "sorted list of numbers" using recursion like this, it will work, but not to choose a random number this way, I don't think

Comment: The divide-and-conquer-method is similat to the binary search. But it only works, if the number of objects is $2^n$ for some $n\in\ \mathbb N$